# Banco de Dados - lista tabela

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, pdo

Pessoal como posso lista todas as tabela do BD e colocar em uma tabela, lista ou em qualquer um canto da pagina?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método abaixo ira retornar todas as tabelas do seu BD.

```
 public function listTable(){
    $query = $this->pdo->query('SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES');
    return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);   
}
```

Comment: Como posso colocar em um SELECT OPTION?